# what is the easiest way to check for the equality of two db rows using groovy sql

Tags: groovy

Is there a simple and concise way to check that two rows of a given Table contains the same data in all columns?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/272110 shows an example uisng dbunit but not pure groovy sql

Comment: Do you mean you have the two rows and you want to compare them, or you want to find all duplicate rows in a database table?

Comment: @tim_yates I have two rows and I want to compare them

Comment: And `a == b` doesn't work?  Some example of what you've tried and failed to get working might help if you added it to the question...  Or, I suspect that Don has the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it seems the most obvious solution:

```
// get an Sql instance
def db = [url:'jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDB', user:'sa', password:'',
    driver:'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver']
def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)

// Get 2 rows
GroovyRowResults row1 = sql.firstRow("select * from user where id = 4")
GroovyRowResults row2 = sql.firstRow("select * from user where email = 'me@example.org'")

// compare them
boolean identical = row1.equals(row2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not especally Groovy, but I'd make SQL do the lifting a la something like:

```
db.firstRow("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(city,state,zip)) FROM Candidates WHERE id IN (1,2)")[0] == 0
```